# Writing Equation in latex

Tags: equations, amsmath, split

I am new to Latex. I am trying to write this equation in Latex, but I've been getting the following error: `Missing $`

```
\begin{equation} \label{tranfdc}
\begin{split} 
T_v(s) &= \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{V_{dcref}(s)} &= \frac{\omega _B}{B} 
\frac{k_{pdc}s + k_{idc}} {s^2 + \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + 
\frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}} \\

 T_i(s) &= \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{i_{l}(s)} &= - \frac{\omega _B}{B} \frac{s} {s^2 
+ \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}} 

\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: No blank lines allowed in math mode.  If you like them for appearance sake in the source, you could always make the blank line a simple `%` instead.

Comment: You may want to defne a new variable `\omega_B' \equiv \omega_B / B` to clean up those equations.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

- empty lines are forbidden in math environments
- environment `split` allow only one ampersand per equation line

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt]{book}
  \usepackage{amsmath}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{equation} \label{tranfdc}
  \begin{split}
  T_v(s) & = \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{V_{dcref}(s)}
           = \frac{\omega _B}{B}
  \frac{k_{pdc}s + k_{idc}} {s^2 + \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} +
  \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}} \\
  %
   T_i(s) & = \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{i_{l}(s)}
            = - \frac{\omega _B}{B} \frac{s} {s^2
  + \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}}
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  \end{document}
  ```

Answer (score 8):

Seeing as in your original MWE you tried adding two `&` symbols per line, perhaps that means you were trying to align the equations at two points? i.e. you wanted both sets of equal signs to be aligned.

If so, then this is possible using `alignat` like so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}\label{tranfdc}
T_v(s) & = \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{V_{dcref}(s)}
         && = \frac{\omega _B}{B}
\frac{k_{pdc}s + k_{idc}} {s^2 + \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} +
\frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}} \\
%
 T_i(s) & = \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{i_{l}(s)}
         && = - \frac{\omega _B}{B} \frac{s} {s^2
+ \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

If you want just one equation number for this set of equations, then use `alignedat` and `equation`. Note the difference between `alignat` and `alignedat`!

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}\label{tranfdc}
T_v(s) & = \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{V_{dcref}(s)}
         && = \frac{\omega _B}{B}
\frac{k_{pdc}s + k_{idc}} {s^2 + \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} +
\frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}} \\
%
 T_i(s) & = \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{i_{l}(s)}
         && = - \frac{\omega _B}{B} \frac{s} {s^2
+ \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to fixing the two syntactical errors -- (i) blank lines in a display-math environment; (ii) more than 1 `&` alignment point in a `split` environment -- you may also wish to make the equations more readable. I'd like to suggest that you (a) not use `\frac` macros in the two long denominator terms (use inline-style fraction notation instead) and (b) render the variable names (esp. `dcref`) in math-italics for more even interletter spacing and "snug up" the space between `V` and `\omega` and their respective subscript terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' env.
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % "variable name"
\renewcommand\!{\mkern-1.5mu} % optional; default is "\mkern-3mu"
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{tranfdc}
\begin{split} 
T_v(s) &= \frac{V_{\!\vn{dc}}(s)}{V_{\!\vn{dcref}}(s)} 
   = \frac{\omega_{\!B}}{B} \frac{k_{\vn{pdc}}s + k_{\vn{idc}}} {s^2 + k_{\vn{pdc}} \omega_{\!B} s/B + 
k_{\vn{idc}} \omega_{\!B}/B} \\
 T_i(s) &= \frac{V_{\!\vn{dc}}(s)}{i_{l}(s)} 
    = - \frac{\omega_{\!B}}{B} \frac{s} {s^2 + k_{\vn{pdc}} \omega_{\!B} s/B + k_{\vn{idc}} \omega_{\!B}/B} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And subscripts that represent nouns are even better typeset upright rather than italics. See e.g. the [IUPAC  Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf), p.5.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - Thanks! An advantage of using the `\vn` ("variable name") approach used in this answer is that (assuming, of course, that `\vn` is used consistently in all formulas involving subscripts (and, possibly, superscripts)...) it's trivially easy to switch the style from italic to upright lettering, merely by changing `\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}}` to `\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}}`. BTW, I don't claim any originality here -- I picked up the `\vn` method some time ago from an @egreg answer!

Comment: In fact, when writing equations, I use the command `\tsub`, again borrowed from an [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303524/50910) ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - What can I say but "great minds think alike"! :-)

Answer (score 5):

I have used the option `align*` without enumeration. It is the same result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}\label{tranfdc}
T_v(s) & = \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{V_{dcref}(s)} =  
 \frac{\omega _B}{B} \frac{k_{pdc}s + k_{idc}} {s^2 + \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}} &\\
T_i(s) & =  \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{i_{l}(s)} = - \frac{\omega _B}{B} \frac{s} {s^2 
+ \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

With the enumeration of the formulas:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{tranfdc}
T_v(s) & = \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{V_{dcref}(s)} =  
 \frac{\omega _B}{B} \frac{k_{pdc}s + k_{idc}} {s^2 + \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}} &\\
T_i(s) & =  \frac{V_{dc}(s)}{i_{l}(s)} = - \frac{\omega _B}{B} \frac{s} {s^2 
+ \frac{ k_{pdc} \omega _B s} {B} + \frac{k_{idc} \omega _B} {B}}\\
\nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Given that I have received a negative reputation I kindly ask you to explain the reason. Thank you.

Comment: i liked your answer, so +1!

Comment: I've also upvoted your answer.